# data validation during full flow of executed methods

Tags: php

This question is have no programming language scope.

Assume we have few functions/methods that our controller action or any service use.

```
class Controller {
    function ourAction () {
        $document = $this->getDocumentFromDB();

        if (!$document) {
            throw new NotFoundException;
        }

        $this->mailer->send($document);
    }
}

class Mailer {
    function send ($document) {
        if (!$document) {
         throw \Exception('Document parameter is empty');
        }
    }
}
```

Is there need to check for document existence in **mailer->send()** or it is not necessary, because of controller action validation?

Comment: I'd suggest to add code snippets according to the tagged languages to avoid further downvotes from confused users.

Comment: Theoretically, Mailer shouldn't have any clue that your controller exists, or what it does. Mailer should handle it's own validation. This way, you can use Mailer from anywhere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling

Answer (score 0):

I would use type hinting instead:

```
class Mailer {
    function send (MailableDocument $document) {
    }
}

interface MailableDocument {
    //whatever document methods you use in the mailer
}
```

PHP will do the dirty job for you.

**EDIT:**

There is no need to check it in controller:

```
class Controller {
    function ourAction () {
        try {
            $this->mailer->send($this->getDocumentFromDB());
        } catch (\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
            throw new NotFoundException(null, null, $e); //whatever parameters it requires.
        }
    }
}

class Mailer {
    function send ($document) {
        if (!$document) {
         throw \UnexpectedValueException('Document parameter is empty');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some cases, when it is not possible. In case $document is array, maybe there is need to validate its emptyness

Comment: Sure thing. It wont work with procedural php4 either. As Magnus said, `Mailer` should be self-contained, and check if all data required for normal operation have been passed. Without any assumption in which context it was called, and what checks were done before. See updated answer.